# redirect with php not working

Tags: php, ajax, redirect, http-headers

I have a file that,  when called, should redirect to another location.
In order to make sure that nothing is sent before the header, I call a file whose only content is the header. I also tried to redirect with other methods, but nothing seems to work. Here is the code:

first there is an ajax call that (successfully) sends some data to file1.php

```
$.ajax({
      url: "file1.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {id:10},
      success: function(){
      },
      error: function (){
      }
});
```

the file1.php gets the data and calls bridge.php

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $selected_id      = $_POST['id'];
}
 require('./code/bridge.php');
?>
```

the file bridge.php should redirect to the new url. I tried the following (not simultaneously)
1.

```
<script>location.href='https://www.google.al/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=l82QVqyAHIb6O5bJs6gK'</script>
```

2.

```
<?
 echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL= https://www.google.al/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=l82QVqyAHIb6O5bJs6gK">'; 
?>
```

3.

```
<?
  header("location: /edit_document"); 
?>
```

4.

```
<?
  ob_start();
  header("location: /edit_document");
?>
```

I am using firebug to see the response. It gives a status 200 (request was fulfilled). POST gives the right parameter that I sent. Response gives the  page where I am trying to redirect. But redirect won't happen.

I reduced the code to this point to eliminate all things that might cause problems. I know you might be wondering why would I write a code that seems to do nothing. But if it doesn't work like this, I doubt I could catch the problem with lots of other calls. Also, I intended to use header for redirecting, but tried other options out of desperation.

Comment: Put exit(); just after header("location: /edit_document");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making AJAX request to obtain redirect URL and then use it for redirect:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "file1.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {id:10},
  success: function(url){
    window.location.href = url;
  },
  error: function (){
  }
});
```

bridge.php:

```
<?php
print "https://www.google.al/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=l82QVqyAHIb6O5bJs6gK";
?>
```

Comment: I thought about it. The only problem is that if i do that, the id sent will be lost during the redirect. I need this page (file1.php) to get it.

Comment: @amygrimaldi file1.php is getting that ID and then can return URL for redirection based on that ID.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript or Jquery redirection ...
// Behaviour Like HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// Behaviour Like clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";

Answer (score 0):

People want to use `AJAX` so that the page doesn't redirect when submitting form. Strangely you want the opposite but using `AJAX`. Why don't you just create a simple form like this and submit the form when you need to redirect.

```
<form name="myForm" action="file1.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="10" />
</form>
```

And just replace your code of ajax (`$.ajax({...});`) with this.

```
document.myForm.submit();
```

If your form has `id="myForm"` instead of `name="myForm"`, this will provide the same result:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

And if you want to modify the id dynamically from the js, you can do it this way (put the code before `submit()` ) :

```
document.myForm.id.value = 20;
```

Comment: In this particular task I am trying to complete, using a form is not an option. I have used forms in the same project for other things. But the data here is taken from a table.

Comment: See the bottom part of my answer, you can get the data from your table and set to the input and you can keep the form hidden as the input field is hidden, it will not be visible as a form in the page.